# Delete rows depending on values in certain columns in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a database table in visual studio which I made using a C# script. The table is a `DataRow` type. In this table there are sometimes rows which have the exact same values in two columns but can be different in the other columns. I want to retain only one of these rows, so I want to delete the other rows which are the same. Does anyone have an idea how I can do this?

I thought of looping through the table, but I do not really know how to delete a row when looping, since I am a beginner in visual studio and C#.

The table looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of table]

I this example the second and third rows are the same in the specified columns, so I want to delete one of these rows

Comment: dt = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Col A") != "abc").CopyToDataTable();

Comment: Could you give a bit more explanation on what this command is doing precisely?

Comment: You can select distinct rows.

Comment: But the rows are not completely identical, only in all but one column the rows are identical

Comment: Taking your example table. Which entries (rows) do you wish to keep?

Comment: I want to keep rows 1,4,5,6 and 7. This is, however part of my table, you can't see the other columns

Comment: The code is filtering using a Where and then copying results to a new datatable.  I'm using a NOT (!=) in the filter but you can use any logical operation(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can use GroupBy to get the first matching element.

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("VariableRowC", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("VariableColumn", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Whatever", typeof(string));

table.Rows.Add("r140","c080","A");
table.Rows.Add("r150","c080","B");
table.Rows.Add("r150","c080","C");
table.Rows.Add("r010","c080","D");
table.Rows.Add("r020","c080","E");
table.Rows.Add("r030","c080","F");
table.Rows.Add("r060","c080","G");
table.Rows.Add("r140","c080","H");
table.Rows.Add("r010","c080","I");

var result = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(d => d.Field<string>("VariableRowC")).Select(e => e.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain what the d and e are? I suppose that these are the columns which I want to check? And what does the "VariableRowC" mean?

Comment: Sorry for my questions, but I am a beginner to c# and visual studio

Comment: I'm using LINQ. `GroupBy` and `Select` are [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions). d and e are parameter variables, but could be named whatever you want. Example: `new int[]{1,2,3}.Where(x => x >= 2)` will select the last two numbers. x in this case is of type int.